# Hibernate Spring Data native query not able to UPDATE set NULL with MERGE INTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, nativequery

First of all, I have a working query for `MERGE INTO` if I directly run it on database. I want to `SET` `NULL` to some columns with `MERGE INTO` `WHEN MATCHED THEN` part. It simply doesn't work when I use it with Hibernate.

This is how my method looks like :

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "MERGE INTO APP_TOKEN t " +
                "USING DUAL " +
                "ON (  t.TYPE      = :appTokenType " +
                "  AND t.TOKEN     = :token " +
                "  AND t.IS_DELETE = 0 " +
                ") " +
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                "  UPDATE SET " +
                "    t.APP_USER_ID   = :appUserId, " +
                "    t.APP_DEVICE_ID = :appDeviceId, " +
                "    t.EXPIRY_DATE   = :expiryDate, " +
                "    t.UPDATED_DT    = :updatedDt, " +
                "    t.UPDATED_BY    = :updatedBy " +
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                "  INSERT (APP_USER_ID, APP_DEVICE_ID, TYPE, TOKEN, EXPIRY_DATE, IS_DELETE, STATUS, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DT, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DT) " +
                "  VALUES (:appUserId, :appDeviceId, :appTokenType, :token, :expiryDate, :isDelete, :status, :createdBy, :createdDt, :updatedBy, :updatedDt) ")
int upsert(@Param(value = "appUserId")        Long         appUserId,
           @Param(value = "appDeviceId")      Long         appDeviceId,
           @Param(value = "appTokenType")     String       appTokenType,
           @Param(value = "token")            String       token,
           @Param(value = "expiryDate")       Date         expiryDate,
           @Param(value = "isDelete")         Boolean      isDelete,
           @Param(value = "status")           String       status,
           @Param(value = "createdBy")        Long         createdBy,
           @Param(value = "createdDt")        Date         createdDt,
           @Param(value = "updatedBy")        Long         updatedBy,
           @Param(value = "updatedDt")        Date         updatedDt);
```

The `appUserId` (first parameter) of the method may be `NULL`, and I want to update this column to `NULL` (in database) if the parameter is `NULL` (in Java).

The following exception is thrown when the `appUserId` is `NULL` :

```
java.sql.sqlsyntaxerrorexception ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected number got binary
```

Framework/ Library I used :

- Spring MVC  5.0.4.RELEASE
- Spring Data JPA 2.0.0.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.16.Final

Database : Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Is Hibernate able to handle setting `NULL` with `UPDATE` ?

EDIT :
I have tried with simple `UPDATE ... SET ...` statement to set some column to `NULL`, but still not successful